# Reconnect to OPC

Tags: c#, opc, opc-da

I am creating an `OPC connection` and I get the data as follows. When the connection is `lost`, the operation does not continue. I need to `reconnect` to OPC when the connection is broken.

How can I do it? or How can I understand that the connection is broken?

```
public Opc.Da.Server Server { get; set; }
public Opc.Da.Subscription GroupRead { get; set; }

public Result StartListening()
{
    Result result = new Result(true);

    try
    {
        var surl = string.Format("opcda://{0}", MyOpcClientClass.ServerName);
        var url = new Opc.URL(surl);
        Server = new Opc.Da.Server(new OpcCom.Factory(), null);
        Server.Connect(url, new Opc.ConnectData(new System.Net.NetworkCredential()));

        Server.ServerShutdown += ServerShutdown;

        var group = new Opc.Da.SubscriptionState();
        group.Name = MyOpcClientClass.GroupName;
        group.UpdateRate = MyOpcClientClass.Period;
        group.Active = true;

        GroupRead = (Opc.Da.Subscription)Server.CreateSubscription(group);
        GroupRead.DataChanged += new Opc.Da.DataChangedEventHandler(DataChanged);

        var items = this.MyOpcClientClassFieldMappingList.Select(i => new Opc.Da.Item
        {
            ItemName = i.OpcTagName
        }).ToList();

        GroupRead.AddItems(items.ToArray());

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // error log
    }

    return result;
}

private void DataChanged(object subscriptionHandle, object requestHandle, Opc.Da.ItemValueResult[] values)
{
    try
    {
        // do smth...
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // error log
    }
}
```

Comment: From cmd.exe >NetStat -a will give all connections and status.  You need to close the current connection before you can reconnect.

Comment: @jdweng I can reconnect manually. This is ok. But I am trying to do this with code.  Reconnect automatically when the connection lost.

Comment: A server cannot reconnect.  The server must close and reopen and wait for client to reconnect.  So server must capture the disconnect event.  Now it is possible for a connection to close without a disconnect event.  So usually you implement a keep-alive which is a message with no data sent by client.  When you do not get a keep-alive for a period of time you close connection assuming the connection closed without a disconnect.

Comment: Note that your current setup is basically **waiting** for the server to send you an update when the data changes. When you don't get an update for 5 seconds, you have no way of knowing whether the server crashed, or there simply hasn't been an change to the data. In order to find out if the server is experiencing issues, you need to implement a "checker" that e.g. repeatedly polls the server for a specific value. If that checker experiences an exception, the server may be experiencing issues, and then you can trigger a reconnect algorithm.

Comment: As a simple analogy, if you're waiting for a letter to be sent to you, and it hasn't yet been delivered, that doesn't mean that the sender must invariably have died. There are plenty of other reasons: (1) the sender hasn't needed to write you a letter yet (2) the mailman lost the letter (3) the mailman is stuck in traffic. Option (1) is the most important one to observe, as this means that there isn't an issue, there simply hasn't been a reason to trigger a change event. The absence of a change event is not necessarily indicative of problems.

Comment: Thank you both for your informative explanations.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a single datapoint that you know for sure should always have "good" quality in the OPC Server (like a heartbeat), you could monitor it in DataChanged or somewhere else in your program. When quality goes "bad", attempt a reconnect.

```
if(values[1].Quality.ToString() == "bad") //Where 1 is the datapoint you expect to be good
{
     StartListening();
}
```